# Problema con ListView para marcar item seleccionado segun condicion previa

Tags: android, listview

Soy nuevo programando en Android y me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Tengo una ListView que lleno con datos, y segun la informacion con la que lo voy llenando cambio el color de fondo de la lista (esa parte me funciona bien), el problema lo tengo al momento de querer resaltar uno de esos items cuando lo selecciono (con los items que no le cambie el color de fondo previamente funciona bien y la primera ves que selecciono un item que se le cambie el color Tambien funciona bien. El problema lo tengo cuando quiero pasar de un item al que le cambie el color de fondo a otro q Tambien le cambie el color de fondo y para que lo resalte le tengo que dar doble click y quisiera que sea un solo click, como podria hacer para solucionar ese inconveniente. Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan proporcionar.

Este es el MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Pedido> pedidos;
PedidoAsignadoAdaptador adaptadorPedArm;
ListView listaPedi;
TextView tvBorrar;
int posListaPedi;
String nombreArmador, nroPedido;
boolean antes = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pedidos = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
    listaPedi = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPedidos);
    cargarListas();
    adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listaPedi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            posListaPedi = position;
            nroPedido = pedidos.get(posListaPedi).getNroPedido();

            listaPedi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Pedido test = new Pedido();

                    test = (Pedido)listaPedi.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String st1 = test.getNroPedido();
                    if (antes){
                        if (st1.equals(" 000100029374")) {
                            adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            antes = false;
                            //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }else {
                            adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            antes = false;
                        }
                    }else {

                        if (st1.equals(" 000100029376")) {
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            antes = true;
                            //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        if (st1.equals(" 000100029374")) {
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            antes = true;
                            //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    });

}


public void cargarListas() {

    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029374"));
    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029375"));
    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029376"));
    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029377"));
    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029378"));
    pedidos.add(new Pedido(" 000100029379"));


    adaptadorPedArm = new PedidoAsignadoAdaptador(MainActivity.this, pedidos);
    adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();

    listaPedi.setAdapter(adaptadorPedArm);
}
```

}

Este es el MAinActivity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvPedidos"
    android:layout_width="392dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@color/pressed_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Esta es el xml de la linea de la lista

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPrueba"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Este es el adaptador de la lista

```
public class PedidoAsignadoAdaptador extends BaseAdapter {
private Context contexto;
//    private int id;
private List<Pedido> ListaPedidos;
//   int itemSeleccionado;
```

//    public static int posListaPedi=0;

```
public PedidoAsignadoAdaptador(Context contexto, List<Pedido> listaPedidos) {
    this.contexto = contexto;
    ListaPedidos = listaPedidos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ListaPedidos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ListaPedidos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(contexto).inflate(R.layout.linea_lista, null);

    TextView nroPedido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrueba);
    nroPedido.setText(ListaPedidos.get(position).getNroPedido().toString());
    String test = ListaPedidos.get(position).getNroPedido();

    if (test.equals(" 000100029376"))
         convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    if (test.equals(" 000100029374"))
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

y esta es la clase Pedido

```
public class Pedido {


private String nroPedido;


public Pedido() {
}

public Pedido(String nroPedido) {
    this.nroPedido = nroPedido;

}

public String getNroPedido() {
    return nroPedido;
}

public void setNroPedido(String nroPedido) {
    this.nroPedido = nroPedido;
}
```

}

Comment: Hola Fernando, lo mejor en este caso es agregar otra propiedad, recuerdo alguién pregunto algo similar, permiteme buscar para agregar una respuesta.

Comment: Hola Jorge, aguardo tu nuevo comentario sobre la propiedad mensionada. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Fernando revisa el ejemplo que agregue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es agregar una propiedad que almacene la selección a tu objeto y que esta selección se refleje en tu listado, como ejemplo agrega la propiedad "seleccionado":

```
public class Pedido {


private String nroPedido;
private int seleccionado;

public Pedido() {
}

public Pedido(String nroPedido) {
    this.nroPedido = nroPedido;

}

public String getNroPedido() {
    return nroPedido;
}

public void setNroPedido(String nroPedido) {
    this.nroPedido = nroPedido;
}

public String getSeleccionado() {
    return seleccionado;
}

public void setSeleccionado(int seleccionado) {
    this.seleccionado= seleccionado;
}

}
```

al agregar un campo a tu objeto, puedes configurar los objetos, al dar clic cambia el color de fondo y agrega la propiedad seleccionado:

```
 @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Pedido test = new Pedido();

                test = (Pedido)listaPedi.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Cambia estatus de selección al dar click
                if(test.getSeleccionado()==1){
                      //Quita seleccion
                     test.setSeleccionado(0);                           
                }else{
                      //Agrega seleccion
                     test.setSeleccionado(1);                  
                     view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);         
                }


            }
```

En tu `Adapter`, revisa cuales tienen la propiedad seleccionado y cambia el color.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(contexto).inflate(R.layout.linea_lista, null);

    TextView nroPedido = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrueba);
    nroPedido.setText(ListaPedidos.get(position).getNroPedido().toString());
    String test = ListaPedidos.get(position).getNroPedido();

     // Si fue seleccionado cambia color de fondo.
     if(ListaPedidos.get(position).getSeleccionado == 1){
          convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
      }

     return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Jorge!! pude solucionarlo con tu aporte de agregar el campo seleccionado a la clase pedidos!! Abrazo grande y gracias nuevamente por la ayuda!!

Comment: Excelente @Fernando , me da gusto, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza esto en setOnItemClickListener

```
    listaPedi.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Pedido test = new Pedido();

            test = (Pedido)listaPedi.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String st1 = test.getNroPedido();
            if (antes){
                if (st1.equals(" 000100029374")) {
                    adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    antes = false;
                    //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {
                    adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    antes = false;
                }
            }else {

                if (st1.equals(" 000100029376")) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    antes = true;
                    //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (st1.equals(" 000100029374")) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    antes = true;
                    //adaptadorPedArm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Tambien debes pasar tus Layouts a LinearLayout

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias Cesar! Es verdad esta duplicada esa parte, pero la borre y sigue con el mismo comportamiento.

Comment: Disculpa me equivoque, debes borrar estas tres lineas, voy a editar la respuesta

Comment: Sisi las borre pero sigue igual

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por toda la ayuda Cesar!!